# .cpp file not seeing .h file at compile time

Tags: c++

I am trying to compile a unit for a class, which I have split into a `.hpp` and `.cpp` file. The files are called `player.hpp` and `player.cpp`.

I used the command `g++ -c player.cpp`.

Here is `player.hpp`

```cpp
#define PLAYER
#ifndef PLAYER

#include <string>
#include <iostream>

class Player
{
    private:
        char symbol;
        std::string name;
    public:
        Player(char symbol, std::string name);
        std::string makeMove(); // Prompts the player to input a move to make
}

#endif
```

and here is `player.cpp`

```cpp
#include "player.hpp"

Player::Player(char symbol)
{
    this->symbol = symbol;
    this->name = name;
}

std::string Player::makeMove()
{
    std::string playerMove;
    std::cout << this->name << "'s turn.\nPlease make your move (enter as number combination of row and column. ex: 13 = First row, third column)\n";
    std::cin << playerMove;
    return playerMove;
}
```

Here is the output

```
player.cpp:3:1: error: ‘Player’ does not name a type
    3 | Player::Player(char symbol)
      | ^~~~~~
player.cpp:9:6: error: ‘string’ in namespace ‘std’ does not name a type
    9 | std::string Player::makeMove()
      |      ^~~~~~
player.cpp:2:1: note: ‘std::string’ is defined in header ‘<string>’; did you forget to ‘#include <string>’?
    1 | #include "player.hpp"
  +++ |+#include <string>
    2 |
```

It would seem that my `.hpp` file is not being included properly, why?

Comment: I don't think you gave us enough code context. With that said the last error should be easily solved by exchanging the 2 headers. Although you may want to add `#include <string>` to the top of `player.hpp`

Comment: Edit the question to provide a [mre].

Comment: Compilers get every time smarter... It even suggests you to include player.hpp and string. Amazing!

Comment: @drescherjm  Good point. Sorry about that. I included all of the code as they are pretty small and simple files for now. I actually have `#include <string>` inside the .hpp file, as can now be seen. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your `player.hpp`, the order of lines in the include guard is incorrect. It should be:

```
#ifndef PLAYER
#define PLAYER
```

Comment: Yes that seemed to solve it. What a silly error. Thank you!